# Как вместо стрелки передавать следующую картинку?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

Работаю со `slick slider` Моя задача в том, чтобы вместо стрелки была картинка. Это не сложно. Сложность в том, чтобы кнопкой `slick-next` была картинка следующая в карусели. То есть пользователь видит превью следующей картинки, и по клику на нее меняется в карусели на нее. Кто то знает как решить это реализовать? Первый вариант менять url.

Answer (score 0):

Там есть методы init,beforeChange,afterChange вот в этих келбеках нужно брать следующую картинку (url из массива и т.д в зависимости от логики) и ставить её фоном в кнопку. Возможно вам не придётся городить велосипед, есть плагин который поддерживает autowidth https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autowidth.html